# Visions of false gods

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

How does Judaism and Kabbalah explain occurrences and visions of false gods like Jesus to Christians, Shiva to Hindus, Muhammad to Sufis in dreams, some of these like Jesus even appear to non-Jewish non-Christians which wouldn’t make sense since if he is actually ha-satan it makes no difference since those people are already steeped in idolatry or in some cases outright occultism.

You also have Christians that claim his name banishes demons, and that demons attack them for believing in him and also that demons work to destroy his religion.

I’m a Noahide and I was born Christian and was into Buddhism and Hinduism for a few years and when I sought the God of Torah I didn’t know better and became Christian again for a while and the first day I converted I started having demonic attacks in sleep paralysis. So I know these are not made up stories but I was wondering how to explain all of this.

Even though I know the Greek testament is in contradiction to Torah and it’s principles I sometimes fear and doubt I’m wrong because of all these stories especially in charismatic circles.

Charismatics even claim Catholic saints are actually demons and that they are secretly steeped in occultism and demonology and also that they have seen people in hell for rejecting their supposed messiah in their particular charismatic way or rejecting a certain pastor etc.

I heard that Jesus is an anti-messiah. How do we explain these visions and their tangible proofs like healings etc?

Is it a test from Hashem? Why test those already steeped in idolatry or occultism or even appearing to some secular Jews and others like some messianic ministries claim?

My mother had a dream with this guy telling her to throw away certain rock music records in her house and later she found out that band were satanic worshippers.

It just seems so confusing to me.

On the other hand I prayed for two years for demonic dreams and attacks to stop to this guy and they didn’t yet when I asked a famous tzaddik to help me for the first time I had a wholesome sleep.

I didn’t even do Pidyon Nefesh yet I saw him in a dream last night smiling and I had a good nights sleep for the first time.

He’s a well-known rebbe but I prefer to keep it confidential.

Comment: Bernard, the people.who know the answers to questions like this are unlikely to post them on the internet....and people who post answers to questions like this on the internet are unlikely to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to filter out all the stories that are made up. Then you have to filter out the stories that are due to mental illness or drugs. As for the remaining stories, the Bible (Deuteronomy 13) teaches us that G-d sometimes sends false prophets to test us. Sometimes these prophets can even perform miracles.

It is also possible for people to be fooled by receiving visions from unholy sources. This is explained at length in the classic work [The Way of G-d:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derech_Hashem)

> Regarding the false prophets: However the essence of this matter is that which we wrote in Part I, Chapter 5 (On the Spiritual Realm 8) about **those powers of impurity that exist in the world** and which work according to that which is embedded in their natures and given over into their hands. **And behold they have the power to fool people to bring down influences on people in ways similar to the ways of true prophecy and reveal true and false things to them. And some wondrous things will happen for him [in this way], as it is written in Scripture explicitly about the false prophet (Deuteronomy 13:2-3), "and he gives you a sign or a wonder. And the sign or wonder happens."** **And note that it is possible for this thing to happen to a person without willing it, and it is possible that it happen to a person willfully.** This means that it is possible that this thing happen to him when he did not make efforts towards it or [even] when he made efforts towards its opposite; but it came to him [regardless], because he had not perfected his deeds and his efforts. But it is [also] possible that he wants it and evilly makes efforts to attain it. This means that he follows these powers and makes efforts to cleave to them, due to his desire to attain that which he wants to attain from them - meaning that matters be revealed to him, as we mentioned; so that through them he can hold himself up to be a prophet in front of people and mislead them as he desires or become honored in their eyes. And of this type were the prophets of Ba'al and Asheirah. For see that they made efforts towards this until they were cleaving to those powers and attained some knowledge of things - through which they they would seduce those who believed them - and also bring forth wonders through this power, as a sign of their being prophets. But they themselves would know that this only came to them from the angle of the impurity they had chosen for themselves. So they themselves did not think they were prophets, but did it out of the evil of their hearts. Yet it was also possible that this would happen to someone who was not making efforts towards it, as we have mentioned. And therefore those making efforts to [attain true] prophecy needed an established teacher to teach them, as we have written - so they would be prevented [from such errors] by him. And all of this is until they would reach the level of true prophecy. For once they reached it, they would already see the great difference and recognize it. Then it would be impossible for them to have doubts about it at all, as we wrote.

Unfortunately there have been people in history who claimed to be Rabbis and yet encouraged people to pray to them, which is idolatry. Their followers will tell of the many miracles these so-called Rabbis performed; yet it is all idolatry.

We do not pray to Rabbis, we only pray directly to G-d. As we say in the [Thirteen Principles of Faith:](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Additional_Prayers_%2C_Thirteen_Principles.6?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

> 5. I believe with complete faith that the Creator, blessed is His Name, is the only One to Whom it is proper to pray, and to no being beside Him is it proper to pray.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: My pleasure. If the answer is satisfactory, you could put a check mark. If you have any follow-up questions, let me know and if I can help you I will, bl'n.

Comment: Oke I just did brother